# How to fix java.lang.NoSuchMethodError even if such a method exist, and error do not occur in local server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat8

I am getting the following error in my Spring MVC web Application.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.smartwcm.core.reservation.service.CrentalReservationService.saveOrUpdateReservation(Lcom/smartwcm/commons/reservation/to/CrentalReservationTO;)Lcom/smartwcm/commons/reservation/to/CrentalReservationTO;
```

I have no issues when I execute the code in my local server. But when the code is deployed to a QA server, I get the above error.

The method that is specified in the error is :

```
public void saveOrUpdateReservation(CrentalReservationTO reservation) throws CrentalException 
    {
        crentalReservationDao.saveOrUpdateReservation(reservation);
    }
```

and the `CrentalReservationTO`  is:

```
public class CrentalReservationTO 
{
    public CrentalReservationTO() 
    {
        super();
    }

    private int reservationId;
    private String reservationStatus;
    private int userCreated;
    private int userModified;
    private Date createdTime;
    private Date updatedTime;
    private int userId;
}
```

The default constructor was added once I started getting the error, but it has not resolved the issue.

Comment: Check for older versions of your jar on your test server

Comment: The class com.smartwcm.core.reservation.service.CrentalReservationService has a different version in QA. You should compile the project again, undeploy all jars in QA and the deploy the final war

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method signature you posted is

```
void saveOrUpdateReservation(CrentalReservationTO reservation)
```

but from the exception message

```
saveOrUpdateReservation(Lcom/smartwcm/commons/reservation/to/CrentalReservationTO;)
Lcom/smartwcm/commons/reservation/to/CrentalReservationTO;
```

Your code is calling

```
CrentalReservationTO saveOrUpdateReservation(CrentalReservationTO reservation)
```

You might have changed a class and not recompiled all dependent classes.

Comment: Thanks, the code was not compiled, it was supposed to build automatically, but dint happen for some reason